# $\phi$ in $O_K$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have this problem:

Let $t$ be a root of the polynomial $f(x) = x³ + x² - 2x + 8$. Let $\phi = \displaystyle \frac{4}{t}$
and let $K = \mathbb{Q}(t)$.

I was able to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible, and that $\phi$ is in $O_K$. However, I am not sure how to show that $\phi$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @subzer0155: It really help readability to use LaTex and MathJax. Regards

Comment: Yes. Forgive my first post. I will use it next time. Thanks Amzoti.

Comment: The choice of notation here is strange: $p$ in a number theory problem for an algebraic number? Use something like $\alpha$.

Comment: You are right. It is just a notation however. I know that mathematicians give great attention to notations.

Comment: Someone already used your previous notation $p$ in an answer, so it's not good for referencing to have changed that now. I also think it is weird to use $\phi$ instead. Look, if you had to pick a point in the plane, would you write its coordinates as $(x,b)$?  That's basically what it feels like when you have an element $t$ and then write $4/t$ as $\phi$. Maybe $\tau$, maybe $u$, but $\phi$...?

Comment: I understand that $p$ would have been mistaken for a prime number. I don't see any issue in using $\phi$. I don't believe that your analogy applies here. Anyway, I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a little more simply than @awllower answers, I say
\begin{align*}
0&=t^3+t^2-2t+8\\
8/t&=-t^2-t+2\\
4/t&=1-\frac12t-\frac12t^2\,,
\end{align*}
and since $\{1,t,t^2\}$ is a basis for $K$ over $\mathbb Q$ (here’s where irreducibility gets used), the coefficients $1,-1/2,-1/2$ are uniquely determined.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have shown that $f(x)$ is irreducible, if $t$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $3$, then that polynomial should be a multiple of $f(x)$. Now, if $p=at^2+bt+c$, then $at^3+bt^2+ct-4=0$, so that $a,b$ cannot be integers, i.e. $p$ cannot lie in $\mathbb Z[t]$.
P.S. In fact $a=b=-1/2$, $c=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\rm\ \exists\,\phi,g\in\Bbb Z[t]\!:\,\ 4\, =\, t\, \phi(t) + f(t)\, g(t),\ $ eval at $\rm\ t=0\: \Rightarrow\: 4=8\,g(0),\ $ contra $\rm\ g(0)\in \Bbb Z\:$

**Remark** $\ $  So, more generally: $ $  if $\rm\,n\in\Bbb Z,\,\ f\in \Bbb Z[t]\,$ then $\rm\ t\mid n\,\ in\,\ \Bbb Z[t]/(f)\ \Rightarrow\ f(0)\mid n\,\ in\,\ \Bbb Z$

Therefore, defining $\rm\ norm(t)\,:=\, f(0),\ $ we have:  $\rm\ \ t\mid n\,\ in\,\ \Bbb Z[t]/(f)\iff norm(t)\mid n\,\ in\,\ \Bbb Z$

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t see that $f(4/t)=0$.

Comment: @Lubin Question was revised, so my answer is now revised.

Comment: The only revision done was changing $p$ to $\phi$ for not to be mistaken for a prime number.

Comment: @subzero155 As was remarked, the notation/phrasing of the question is somewhat unusual (which led me to read it as a different problem in its first revision).